# Props are undefined in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props, reactstrap

I'm new to `js` and `reactjs`. I'm trying to create a `ButtonGroup` with few `Buttons` inside, in hope of when I click a particular `Button` (in `ButtonGroup`) only that particular button will get highlighted (change colour) and rest will be of normal colour.
Below is the code which does the above behaviour but in `setColour` method I'm getting an error `_this.state.selected.props is undefined`. Could someone point out the where I'm getting wrong ? Also, if someone can tell me if this is the correct way to approach this problem.

```js
import React from "react"
import {
    ButtonGroup,
    Button
} from "reactstrap"


class MainButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selected: null
    }
}

handleSelection = (e) => {
    this.setState({selected: e.target})
}

setColour = (key) => {
    if (this.state.selected)
    {
        // ERROR : _this.state.selected.props is undefined
        return (this.state.selected.props.key === key) ? 'primary' : 'secondary'
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <ButtonGroup>
            <Button key={1} onClick={this.handleSelection} color={this.setColour(1)}>MainButtonA</Button>
            <Button key={2} onClick={this.handleSelection} color={this.setColour(2)}>MainButtonB</Button>
            <Button key={3} onClick={this.handleSelection} color={this.setColour(3)}>MainButtonC</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
    )
}
}

export default MainButtonsGroup;
```

Comment: You cannot get the props of a component from a DOM node.

Comment: `e.target` is the underlying DOM element of the event target. Also, keys are supposed to be used exclusively and internally by React, instead keep a record of the current selection in state. You can pass an index to `handleSelection` and set in state

Comment: Just `this.props.key`

Comment: You should try to achieve this with css. Set a particular className on a Button based on this.state.selected. Check out https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames for some ideas and also using that library isn't a bad idea.

Comment: From the react docs, https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way. `// Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
  this.setState({clickEvent: event});`

Comment: thanks for your response !
I don't have much reputation to up vote the answer therefore this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not hold on to the e.target reference and you must be getting a React warning in your console about it? You just created a memory leak in your app.

Instead copy what you need from the target and let the reference be garbage collected. Although in your case there's no need to be attaching data to the DOM node:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.handleSelection(this.setColour(3))}>MainButtonC</Button>
```

Note you don't need `key={3}` unless you're mapping the elements in a loop.

```
handleSelection = (color) => {
    this.setState({ selected: color })
}
```

However this code is a bit strange, just record the index of the clicked button and give it a class to style it e.g.

```
class MainButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedIndex: null,
  }

  handleSelection = (index) => {
    this.setState({selectedIndex: index})
  }

  render() {
    const idx = this.state.selectedIndex;

    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button className={idx === 1 ? 'primary' : 'secondary'} onClick={() => this.handleSelection(1)}>MainButtonA</Button>
        <Button className={idx === 2 ? 'primary' : 'secondary'} onClick={() => this.handleSelection(2)}>MainButtonB</Button>
        <Button className={idx === 3 ? 'primary' : 'secondary'} onClick={() => this.handleSelection(3)}>MainButtonC</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response !
I don't have much reputation to up vote the answer therefore this comment.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the props of a component from a DOM node. You could instead keep your button names in an array in your component state and use that to render your buttons in the render method.

You can then pass in the button name to the `handleSelection` and use that as your `selected` value. If your button is the selected one it can be given the `primary` color, otherwise the `secondary` one.

**Example**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ButtonGroup, Button } from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class MainButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttons: ["A", "B", "C"],
      selected: null
    };
  }

  handleSelection = button => {
    this.setState({ selected: button });
  };

  render() {
    const { buttons, selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        {buttons.map(button => (
          <Button
            key={button}
            onClick={() => this.handleSelection(button)}
            color={selected === button ? "primary" : "secondary"}
          >
            MainButton{button}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response !
I don't have much reputation to up vote the answer therefore this comment.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention it, but button names would come from `this.props` so probably, we don't need them part of `this.state`.